# Creating users table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have some trouble with the laravel's users table. I already deleted those default table long time ago. And now I am trying to use Auth but I can't register. because there is no table in the database. But also i can't create table with `php artisan migrate.` because I already deleted those migration tables. So I want create those tables once more. But I couldn't find the default files.

And make:auth is doesn't bring the table... I need to recreate it by myself. I remember there two diffrent tables back then one is users and reset password? Do anyone know where can I get thoese tables again?

Comment: I suppose you can use the [default ones](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/database/migrations) found in the public git to replace the ones you've deleted. While it may not solve your problem completely, it's a good starting point.

Comment: Do you need to create default users table?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just run these commands

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table
php artisan make:migration create_password_resets_table
```

In your migration create_users_table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

In your migration create_password_resets_table

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('password_resets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('email')->index();
            $table->string('token');
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
        });
    }
```

after that run

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

PS: This will reset your database
Or just run

```
php artisan migrate
```

EDIT: If facing error  `1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes`

In your `AppServiceProvider.php` add this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema; //this

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191); //this
}
```

Comment: Thank you mate, this is what I want! I check your answer!

Comment: but it's giving me this error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`)) when I try to migrate

Comment: edit your AppServiceProvider.php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}

Comment: Edited answer please check

Comment: File is located at
{ProjectLocation}/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

Comment: yes, error is changed `Class 'App\Providers\Schema' not found` this is going where? {/var/www/html/laravel}/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

Comment: add 
"use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;"
 (without quotes) after namespace above the class

Comment: I already done that, but just create users not the resets table? Do you know why is that?

Comment: In auth password reset is required (in default auth mode).
There should be another issue please share the error log

Comment: I was looking for the answers and managed to find yours. This solves my issues. thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can retrieve those deleted migrations from laravel repository :
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/database/migrations

2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php :

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table.php :

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
class CreatePasswordResetsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('password_resets', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('email')->index();
            $table->string('token');
            $table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
        });
    }
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('password_resets');
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21387296)

Comment: Please add some explanation to that code such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase I think this is clear for one who know laravel, but if I can, sure I will add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You should run below command:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

then run below command

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: did you read the question? make auth doesn't bring the users and reset password table

Comment: @Snickers: Please check migration folder you have any users migration file

Comment: no there isn't. because I delete those long time ago. and make:auth doesn't bring those.

Comment: @Snickers You need to install new fresh version of the laravel and copy the user migration file from new version and past in your current version then  you can perform the above command , it will works...